# http relay using php

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm trying to relay http traffic from apache to custom built apps running on different
ports ( something like fast cgi ) , but far more simplified.

on the app side i have a http server.

on the apache side i have this

```
         <?php
         require 'aagateway.php';
         $r = new aaGateway();
         $r->connect();

         $r->send("GET ".$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]." HTTP/1.11\n"); 
         foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) { $r->send("$name: $value\n"); }
         $r->send("\n");

         while(1)
          {
          $t=$r->get_response();
          $sl=strlen($t);
          if($sl==0) break;
          header($t);
          }

         echo $r->get_response();

         return;
         ?>
```

the request and associated headers are received by the app correctly.

My problem is, how do i then get the response headers from the app and pass them to apache.
(the problem is in the header($t);
Its not setting the headers

Comment: Use nginx instead (http://nginx.org/)

Comment: get_response and send are just straight tcp read and write they dont do anything